# Unable to call through swizzling AppDelegate instance method application(_:open:options:) by clicking on URL scheme deep link

Tags: ios, swift

I use absolutely the same approach to swizzle two `AppDelegate` instance methods - universal and URL scheme links. I need to mention that both test links has correctly setup. I tried to check how this approach works on the iOS 12 and 13 and got a same unexpected behavior.

In the case when I trying to click by the universal link everything works as expected. In the case when I try to do the same with URL scheme link I see that the successfully swizzled method `application(_:open:options:)` do not fired up by the system.

If I initialize two empty methods `application(_:open:options:)` and `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` at the `AppDelegate` class and than call `method_exchangeImplementations` from my code below I received successfully changed implementation of `application(_:open:options:)` and `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` methods. When I try to do the click by the universal link or by the URL scheme link in both cases I received expected behavior - system fired my swizzled methods.

When I do not initialize the empty methods `application(_:open:options:)` and `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` at the `AppDelegate` class as you can see from my code below I call method `class_addMethod` for adding implementation on the fly to the `AppDelegate` instance. In this case I see that the both methods `application(_:open:options:)` and `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` successfully added to the `AppDelegate` instance but when I try to do the click by the URL scheme link - system has not fired my swizzled method `application(_:open:options:)` and vice versa with method `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` - clicking by the universal link fired my swizzle method.

```swift
// MARK: Swizzle AppDelegate universal links method.

private func swizzleContinueRestorationHandler() {
    guard let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(Swizzler.self, #selector(self.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:))) else { return }

    let delegateClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(UIApplication.shared.delegate)
    let applicationSelector = #selector(UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:))

    if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(delegateClass, applicationSelector) {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzleMethod)
    } else {
        class_addMethod(delegateClass, applicationSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzleMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzleMethod))
    }
}

// MARK: Swizzle AppDelegate URL schemes method.

private func swizzleOpenOptions() {
    guard let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(Swizzler.self, #selector(self.application(_:open:options:))) else { return }

    let delegateClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(UIApplication.shared.delegate)
    let applicationSelector = #selector(UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:open:options:))

    if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(delegateClass, applicationSelector) {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzleMethod)
    } else {
        class_addMethod(delegateClass, applicationSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzleMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzleMethod))
    }
}

// MARK: Swizzled AppDelegate universal links method.

@objc func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
...
}

// MARK: Swizzled AppDelegate URL schemes method.

@objc func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
...
}
```

Why it happens and how to add method `application(_:open:options:)` on the fly to `AppDelegate` instance and get expected behavior after clicking by URL scheme link?

Comment: In iOS 13, `application(_:open:options:)` is not called. The message goes to the scene delegate.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it is true only for new created project at the Xcode 11. For old projects where SceneDelegate is absent like in my case iOS continue fired up functions (_:open:options:) and (_:continue:restorationHandler:).